# Why is std::move used when returning in this function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am just reading into the algorithm.h header of the visual studio implementation of the stl and I found the following code:

```
template<class _InIt,
    class _Fn1> inline
    _Fn1 for_each(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Fn1 _Func)
    {   // perform function for each element
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First, _Last);
    _DEBUG_POINTER(_Func);
    _For_each(_Unchecked(_First), _Unchecked(_Last), _Func);

    return (_STD move(_Func));
    }
```

... the important part of the code is the following:

```
 template<class _InIt, class _Fn1> 
 inline _Fn1 for_each(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Fn1 _Func)
 {  // perform function for each element
    _For_each(_Unchecked(_First), _Unchecked(_Last), _Func);
    return (std::move(_Func));
 }
```

... and here is the signature of the `_For_each` function

```
template<class _InIt,
    class _Fn1> inline
    void _For_each(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _Fn1& _Func)
```

And my question is why is the `std::move` required when returning in this case ?
And for completing the question: In what cases is required to use `std::move` when returning out of a function ? I think could be useful to have this information in a pragmatic way.

Comment: Could you please expand all those macros? It's impossible to tell what the code does if we can't see it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems unnecessary, but it might be a workaround around a compiler bug or limitation.

Comment: With `return std::move(_Func)`, you can be guaranteed of being able to read the mutated state externally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer to your question is the C++11 standard says so.  The implementation of `for_each` is required to return a move-constructable function object/pointer.

From the standard:

> 25.2.4 For each [alg.foreach]
>
> template Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
>   Function f);
>
> 1 Requires: Function shall meet the requirements of MoveConstructible
>   (Table 20). [ Note: Function need not meet the requirements of
>   CopyConstructible (Table 21). — end note ]
>
> 2 Eﬀects: Applies f to the result of dereferencing every iterator in
>   the range [first,last), starting from first and proceeding to last -
>   1. [ Note: If the type of first satisﬁes the requirements of a mutable iterator, f may apply nonconstant functions through the dereferenced
>   iterator.— end note ]
>
> 3 Returns: std::move(f).
>
> 4 Complexity: Applies f exactly last - first times.
>
> 5 Remarks: If f returns a result, the result is ignored.

Item #3 requires `std::for_each` to return `std::move(fn)`.

> And my question is why is the std::move required when returning in
>   this case?

The reason the standard requires it is so that the return value is guaranteed to be a move-constructable function object.

> And for completing the question: In what cases is required to use
>   std::move when returning out of a function?

If you need to, or desire, a function's return value to be move-constructable, you would use `return std::move(...)`.  This allows you to access the state of the return value (in the `for_each` example, the state of a function object/pointer) once the function exits).

For reference, Table 20 of the standard reads:

```
Table 20 — MoveConstructible requirements [moveconstructible]
Expression           Post-condition
T u = rv;            u is equivalent to the value of rv before the construction
T(rv)                T(rv) is equivalent to the value of rv before the construction
[ Note: rv remains a valid object. Its state is unspeciﬁed — end note ]
```